# make me clear for Desktop and mobile view websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, responsive-design

when we develop a website is it also perfect for **mobile view?**
if not then what changes requires if i want to develop for both **desktop view and mobile view?**
please give me suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the desktop/small device browser's (client) send their device info in `request header`.

A server should recognize that. If it can recognize it can process the request as normal flow and delegate to `proper/expected view`.

One example flow can be like this:

Client
 - Deice: Android
 - Resolution: AxY
 - URL: `URL` of the resource to GET

Server:
 - I can recognize the device
 - I am preparing relevant UI for that device (html/jsp/php etc)
 - I have the resource for given `URL`
 - I am preparing the request and sending it

---

**Additionally**
Refer to `Sterlok`s answer. That thing can guide you to prepare the `view`.

However most important part is to recognize the `device (actually client)` and respond accordingly.

For example, a `Java EE` based web-application can achieve this using a `Request Filter`.

Answer (score 6):

Responsive Web Design is what you're looking for:

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design

Google Search: http://www.google.com/search?q=responsive+web+design

Some frameworks that aid in responsive web design:

- Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
- Neat: http://thoughtbot.com/neat/
- Lessframework: http://lessframework.com/
- Skeleton: http://www.getskeleton.com/

there are many others. Hopefully this should set you on the right track.